# Credentials for sip-server in asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk, credentials

It is possible to register to a sip provider with asterisk, namely with the command:

```
register => [peer?][transport://]user[@domain][:secret[:authuser]]@host[:port][/extension][~expiry]
```

What if what I want to do is to setup a sip provider? Not for end-clients, but for a sip-peer? Where can I define the credentials (username/password) that the peer needs to use to connect to my server?

In other words: what I want to setup is an endpoint so that a remote server can register with the `register` command.

Answer (score 0):

Client side libs have no such functionality.

You can check pjsip project

Comment: What client libs? I am talking about asterisk, acting both as server and client. The client can very well connect (there is a register command). I need to know how to setup the server.

Comment: Asterisk can work as client and server. see sip.conf.sample for more info or read asterisk book

Comment: I *obviously* know that asterisk can work as server and client (I am asking for an example configuration about it!), I know there is a sip.conf.sample, I know there is an asterisk book. If I am asking *here* is because I could not find an answer to my problem there. I am looking for a simple configuration example of an authenticated server / client pair, in which both ends are asterisk boxes (that is, they are building an authenticated sip trunk). Any hints about a simple configuration example? I need both client **and** server configurations (for both asterisk boxes)

Comment: Such configuration included in any book about asterisk. I don't know what is your issue. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+-+dual+servers